# windows 8 metro app, Close method was missing in System.Net.HttpWebResponse

Tags: .net, http, windows-8, io

Sometimes the http connection was not closed successfully util app exited in windows 8 metro app, is there anybody have good solutions to close the http connection?

There a **Close** method for **System.Net.HttpWebResponse** in the document below, but I can't find it when coding, the *Close* method also missing in **System.IO.Stream** but exist in the document.

[System.Net.HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx)

[System.IO.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.stream.close.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not all methods (or classes) are supported in all versions of the .Net Framework. If you look at the documentation for the [HttpWebResponse Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx), you will see these methods (among others):

[image: httpwebresponse-methods]

Each method has a symbol which precedes the name:

[image: avail-all]   means that the method is public; it is implied that the method is available for use in projects that use the *full* version of the .Net Framework.
[image: avail-pcl]   means that the method is available for use in *Portable Class Library* projects.
[image: avail-w8-apps]   means that the method is available for use in *Windows Store* projects.

You will note that `Close` and `CreateObjRef` methods are only available in projects that use the full version of the .Net Framework. The `Dispose` method is available for use in all three kinds of .Net projects (full .Net Framework, Portable Class Library, and Windows Store).

To answer your question about properly "closing" each class:

For the `HttpWebResponse` class which implements `IDisposable`, you can just use `using`. This is a c# example, but VB.Net supports `using` also.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1");
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
    // Do something with response object.
    response.DoSomething();
    ...

    // End of "using" block automatically calls "response.Dispose()" 
}
```

The `using` statement will ensure that `Dispose()` is called at the end of the code block. This will clean up the `response` object.

As for cleaning up the `Stream` object - it also implements `IDisposable`, which means you can use `using` for it as well. I also use `Flush`, just to be safe:

```
using (Stream myStream = /* create stream */)
{
    // Do something with stream
    myStream.DoSomething();
    ...

    // Done using stream. Flush it.
    myStream.Flush();
    // End of "using" block automatically calls "myStream.Dispose()" 
}
```

More on the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) at MSDN.